# Show or hide section in HTML with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, visibility

In my HTML file there is an section-element like this:

```
<section id="analysisData" hidden>
  ..
</section>
```

How can I toggle it's visibility with JavaScript? I tried something like this to get it visible:

```
document.getElementById('analysisData').style.visibility='visible';
```

Unfortunately that does not work? Any idea?

Comment: Your question is missing the code for the <section> element. But if your code is not working, I'd suggest trying to change the "display" attribute, rather than visibility. i.e. document.getElementById('analysisData').style.display = "block";

Comment: Do you mean remove the HTML Element from the DOM programmatically using JavaScript? Or update the CSS visibility style? And do you want the HTML Element to take up the same space as it did before it is “hidden”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With pure JS

```
document.getElementById('analysisData').style.display='block'; //to show
document.getElementById('analysisData').style.display='none'; //to hide
```

With jQuery

```
$('#analysisData').toggle()
```